# Channel Views from YouTube API?

Tags: php, json, youtube, youtube-api

I am looking to get the amount of channel views a YouTube channel has through their API.

I have been looking through the documentation and been googling but I cannot seem to find how.

Channel views aren't being shown on actual channels anymore but they are being shown on the mobile site ([example](http://m.youtube.com/user/Google)) and also there are sites which are tracking them still ([example](http://socialblade.com/youtube/user/google)) so I assume that they must be available via the API.

If anyone knows how they are available (preferably outputted with JSON) I would appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to figure it out for anyone wanting to know, this is using `PHP` and `JSON`, using Google's youtube channel as an example.

The URL is: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Google?alt=json

To parse it you would do:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Google?alt=json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo 'Channel Views: ' . $data['entry']['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
```